OneNote for Windows 10 - how to remove fonts from the "Recently Used Fonts" list?

Where/how is the OneNote for Windows 10 app's Recently Used Fonts list stored?

Can you edit this list?







Also - since OneNote for Windows 10 isn't in the Microsoft Store anymore, where can you download the app?




This list is stored in an application registry hive which is separate from the default Windows registry hives seen in regedit.exe.
Download link as of 2024:

Microsoft Store






To edit this list:

Close the OneNote for Windows 10 app

Launch regedit.exe, select either the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or the HKEY_USERS hive and go to File > Load Hive...

Navigate to the following file and click OK
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Settings\settings.dat
Give the hive a name and click OK (e.g. OneNoteSettingsHive)


Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\OneNoteSettingsHive\LocalState\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\Options\FontMru

The list of recently used fonts is stored in this key.

Each value stores a hex representation of the unicode-encoded font name.
Double clicking on a value will show you the name of the font:



Delete any registry values that contain fonts you wish to remove from the "Recently Used Fonts" list.

Make sure that the remaining registry values are named sequentially:


Unmount the hive and close regedit.exe

This step is critical.  If you neglect to unmount the hive, then try to launch OneNote, it will fail to launch and possibly create a new settings.dat hive and overwrite any preferences you had saved.


Open OneNote.  Your "Recently Used Fonts" list should reflect the modifications made in regedit.


